# Is there any tool for me to easy understand the git conflict file?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I merge two branch, but it result the final file like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is line -1.
this is line -2.
this is line -3.
=======
this is line b1.
this is line b2.
this is line b3.
>>>>>>> addSomePrefix
```

I have no ideas what it is represent, is their any GUI tools for display the data in a more human readable format? Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your platform, you might want TortoiseGit:  http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/list  I'm not sure it'll help with this question (I'm not sure what your question *IS* exactly - it looks more like a merge conflict warning than a "config file"!), but it might help in general... IMHO...

Comment: This isn't a config file; this looks like a conflict instead. Suggest you amend the question?

Comment: Looks like a merge conflict. The Head section is the current code and the part below the `=====` is the code that was merged in from branch addSomePrefix.

Comment: This is not git config file, this is a merge conflict created by the `diff` program. For GUI tool, I really like [diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of a conflict.

You should manually edit the file, resolving the conflict (basically that means picking the code you want to stay).

Right now the code above the === is the old code and below the === is your new code (I think it's that way!).

For general git usage I also recommend a gui tool like [gitg](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/) (Linux) / [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/index.html) (Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Some Git clients provide a "diff3" conflict solver tool (a 3 panels wiew helping you to resolve the conflict from a few mouse clicks). You can try for instance [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html).

But, as already said, resolving the conflict manually is also an option, it is not as difficult...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org/) as a visual tool for merging, it does nice 3 way merging showing you the common root and allowing pulling in changes from both sides of the merge.

To have it invoke when you run `git mergetool` add the following to your git configuration

```
[merge]
   summary = false
   tool = "meld"

[mergetool "meld"]
  cmd = meld \
   -a \
   "$PWD/$BASE" \
   "$PWD/$LOCAL" \
   "$PWD/$REMOTE" \
   -o "$PWD/$MERGED"
   keepBackup = false
   trustExitCode = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check ECMerge (the tool I work for), it loads Git conflict files with its "Open conflict file" menu, or from its shell extension, and displays them so as to let you solve the conflict.

By the way, it works for most other VCS (such Bazaar, Darcs, CVS, SVN and so on).

ECMerge is integrated with git, there is a pre-registered tool for it, and it can as well browse Git repositories (local and bare repos) when configured to use the git command line.